# ¿Cómo obtener los máximos para un determinado periodo de estudio con su fecha correspondiente en r?

Tags: r, dataframe

Estoy trabajando con un dataframe que contiene registros de ola desde el 2000, quiero obtener la ola máxima registrada y la fecha correspondiente para un periodo determinado de estudio, es decir, una campaña de trabajo comprende del 01/12/2020 al 01/02/2021, quiero obtener la ola máxima que se registró en ese tiempo y su fecha correspondiente.

Comment: Bienvenida/o a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Sería muy útil para poder responderte que que muestres un ejemplo simple de los dato que estas hablando, por ejemplo mediante `dput(head(tu_df))` y agregues la salida a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que tienes un df de este estilo:

```
olas <- c(7,9,14,4)
fecha <- c("01-12-2020", "07-12-2020","12-03-2021","12-02-2021")       #*imaginemos que son realmente fechas.

df <-data.frame (olas, fecha)

 olas      fecha
1    7 01-12-2020
2    9 07-12-2020
3   14 12-03-2021
4    4 12-02-2021
```

Quieres el máximo de las olas y saber a que fecha corresponde.

Con `which` puedes obtener la posición que ocupa el máximo de olas.

```
posicion_maximo <- which(df == max(df$olas))
```

Y ahora sacas la fecha que ocupa esa posición

```
df[posicion_maximo ,"fecha"]

"12-03-2021"
```

Si hay empate el en máximo de las olas te sacará varias fechas.